# Is there a way to access a websever behind NAT?

Tags: webrtc, nat, stun, turn

I am trying to access a web server behind NAT. The challenge is: because there could be several web servers coexist, router registration based on port is not a feasible solution here.

I apologize this looks more like general question, because I really don't know where to start after reading online sources related to NAT traversal, which technique to choose: proxy, tunnelling, WebRTC, ICE?

I experiment a little bit with libnice. It will output a string which looks like candidate list that can be sent to the remote peer to let it connect in. But it doesn't look obvious how to embed the string in Http URL.

Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have multiple web servers running behind a NAT firewall, by port-forwarding a different port to each web server.

For example:

```
yourip:8080 ->port forward-> web server 0 running on 192.168.1.10
yourip:8081 ->port forward-> web server 1 running on 192.168.1.11
yourip:8082 ->port forward-> web server 2 running on 192.168.1.12
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Although your solution could work, I am afraid it might involve non-trivial configuration and management task for each instance. I forgot to mention that this is a dynamic situation: web servers can be launched and closed at any time. This is a weird case: in my application we set up web server just for sending/receiving data.

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure I understand your question.  If you have multiple web servers running on your LAN (say on 192.168.1.10, 192.168.1.11, 192.168.1.12, etc), all behind a NAT router with just one public IP, then how do you envision a user outside of your LAN indicating which of the web servers that they want to access?

Comment: Are you implying ICE (including STUN or TURN) does not support multiple programs (each on different machine) that listen at the same port? I imagine each program will punch a different hole. Not exactly sure, but I can do some simple test using libnice.

Comment: I think you are probably right. This deals with the topic of TCP NAT traversal and hole punching.